# Lua FFI throws a missing declaration error, even though I wrote a declaration

Tags: c, lua, love2d

first time poster here. I am working on a game program with Lua and Love2D, and in a section of the program I create a list of coordinates and take all unique coordinates and put them inside another list. The program is functional and the effects I use the lists for look great. However, the lists end up being thousands of items long, and the game ends up running at below 20fps. I was hoping I could write a small C program to speed this up and bind it to Lua. I wrote my program, it compiled (after much effort) into a .so library. I load the library into lua (also after much effort) and then it throws the error

```
missing declaration for symbol 'coordinarray'
```

Which is odd, 'cause I do have a ffi.cdef up at the top. So what's going on? I haven't seen anyone have this exact issue, and tutorials I've looked at look identical to my code as far as I can tell:

```
local ffi = require 'ffi'
ffi.cdef = [[

struct coordinates{
    double x;
    double y;
};

bool coordinarray(struct coordinates a, struct coordinates b[]);

]]
local spdmth = ffi.load("./spdmth/libspdmth.so")
```

And then I made a test function call, where the error gets thrown:

```
    spdmth.coordinarray({x = 1, y = 1}, vispass)
```

The function in my C program is also named coordinarray and returns a bool  like in the declaration. Any ideas on how to progress?

Comment: You are assigning to `ffi.cdef` when you should be calling it. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Well, looks like that worked. An embarrassing mistake.